# Should I keep invoices' images after being generated in db?

Tags: database-design

Are there any circumstances where I should keep generated text invoices as an "image" in Database?

Are there any law issues or other where I should keep it in not touch state?

Thanks!

Comment: Who's laws? Besides what does keeping an image in there do for you. You going to hold up it in court and say this is the image we generated, trust me, I never changed it no sir?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: That's exactly what records managers do in court.  And, if they explain how (WORM storage, usually), the court accepts their testimony.  (John): Could be a law, could just be for audit and accountability purposes.  You'd have to ask the people giving you the requirement.

Comment: WORM storage. Smoke screen and a better lawyer. It might be a requirement, it might be based on someone's usage of some law somewhere. It's definitely off topic and a poor question.

Answer (score 0):

We do it in LedgerSMB.  It provides an authoritative record of what the customer received.  There are cases where you may want to be able to look at the actual document and compare it with your records for audit purposes.  Yes, I would recommend doing this.